# Android Studio - Best way to get view instances of an activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-view

I'm quite new to Android Studio and I want to have quick access to views such as buttons, image views, text views, etc.

So far I know the method `findViewById`, and this is what I'm doing to create easy access to views:

```
Button btn1, btn2, btn3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    this.btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    this.btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
}

//then I simply use my defined vars
```

Although it works, it's still quite boring to have to write all this code (or to have to use `findViewById` every time, with a cumbersome way of getting ids and still adding a cast).

Is this really the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You can check out library like Butterknife http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/.

It prevents you from writing boilerplate code - simply inject views. 
You can combine it with this Android Studio plugin: 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7369-android-butterknife-zelezny

With this set up injecting views is really simple and fast.

Also, you can check out topic like "databinding" https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html
It is also a good approach to have views defined for you.

Answer (score 3):

In android O you don't need to write **(Cast)** before the `findViewById`, Also there is third part library called [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) with applying the plugin and generating it you can handle this issue very easy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "In android O you don't need to write findViewById" -- yes, you do. What changed is that you do not need to cast the result.

Answer (score 3):

you can use 3 way :

**1.findViewById**

normal way but The hardest.
you can use plugin findviewbyme ([link](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8261-findviewbyme)) for speed up write code

**2.butterknife Library**

when use this lib, the code gets less.you can check this [link](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

**3.Data Binding Library**

Is the best way, just after initial binding, when add new view in layout, you have access to it without any additional code. you can check this ([link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/say-goodbye-to-findviewbyid-with-data-binding-library/en))

Answer (score 2):

There are libraries such as [AndroidAnnotation](http://androidannotations.org/) and ButterKnife you may be interested in. This is how your code would look like if you use Android Annotation.

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main) 
public class MainActivity extends Actiivty {

   @ViewById    
   Button btn1, btn2, btn3;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has mentioned this in any of their answers, Kotlin is now officially supported for android development and there is the android kotlin extension (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) which allows you to access the views directly without findViewById().

If you do decide to use it, just be aware that if you use it in a fragment, you have to use it after passing the view in onCreateView() or else it will not find the views.

If you are not ready for Kotlin, then I would highly recommend data binding over butterknife or any other solution because this is the direction Google is going with android.